# Juint tests with static class

Tags: java, javafx, junit

So I am trying to test a controller and in my code it has a access to a public static variable created in main on startup called settings. I have tried settings up my Junit tests @Before every way possible to create the same static class that is created in main however nothing is working.

So in my code I have

```
public class Main extends Application {

//static variables that can be referenced from anywhere in the application
public static GameSettingsModel settings;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {

    //initiate the GameSettingsModel
    settings = new GameSettingsModel();

}
```

Then I Im trying to test a controller which uses a function in the static GameSettingsModel settings however I cant get it working.

This is my junit test

```
public class Test extends TestSuite {

private IGame game;
private IBall ball;
private IPaddle paddle;
private IBrick player1Wall;
private IPlayer player1;
private IPlayer player2;

public static GameSettingsModel settings;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    //initiate the GameSettingsModel
    settings = new GameSettingsModel();

    player1Wall = new BrickModel(0,0,20);
    player1 = new PlayerModel();
    player2 = new PlayerModel();
    ball = new BallModel();
    paddle = new PaddleModel();
    game = new SinglePlayerController();
}
```

so now when I try and run the tests I get a NullPointerException on a line where my code try's to call settings.reset();

What is the correct what to give my controller knowledge of the static class during testing? Hope that makes sense

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not really. We need a real [mcve] including the code that throws, and the exception stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either pass the static variable through a constructor that you only use in your test case, or either mock the variable with [PowerMock](http://powermock.github.io/). For example:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ MyStaticClass.class })
public class MyTest {

    @Before 
    public void setup() {
        // Here you mock the variable with the method that is going to be executed    
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(MyStaticClass.class);
        PowerMockito.when(MyStaticClass.staticMethod).thenReturn(result);
    }

}
```

Hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: I just ended up adding a lot of constructors cause i knew i should remove the static variables at some point anyway and it all works

Answer (score 2):

Don't set static variables from instance methods. In fact, don't have mutable static variables. Based on the code you've provided, `settings` should be an instance variable.

Comment: Or even just a local variable that is passed to the controller(s) for the application.